# Take user input and use that value as the filter for a query

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have a C# application (was built using Visual Studio 2015 Professional) that is used to interface with a Microsoft Access (2010) database (.mdb).  First of all...I am not normally a C# Developer, so please excuse the ignorance.  What I want to do seems simple enough...but I cannot figure out how to actually accomplish it.  I am looking to create a search portal that would take the users input, query the database, and return the record that matches the desired Serial Number.

My first thought was to create a query in Visual Studio and use the users input as a filter for the query, but I could not figure out how to set it to look at the inputTB for the value.

My second thought was to nest a SQL query within my C# code...but I do not know they syntax or structure required to do something like that.

The only bit of code I do have is the SQL Query I wanted to use, but it's essentially pseudocode and I'm sure there are gaps in it.

```
SELECT ID, UnitType, UnitSN, StatusCode, Priority
FROM Units
WHERE UnitSN = inputTB;
```

**Edit**

With the help of a couple members of the StackOverflow Community, I have pieced together a bit of code, but I am having trouble displaying the results in the datagrid.  The code that has been generated so far:

```
public void Main()
    {
        string unitSN = inputTB.Text;

        string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.ZeusConnectionString;
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Units WHERE UnitSN LIKE @Name", connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Name", unitSN));

                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    int ID = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    string Unit = reader.GetString(1);
                    string SerialNumber = reader.GetString(2);

                    //Console.WriteLine("ID = {0}, Unit = {1}, SerialNumber = {2}", ID, Unit, SerialNumber);
                    MessageBox.Show(SerialNumber);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please feel free to make any edits to the code as I realize it is a mess and I have little more than a cursory knowledge of the C# language.

Comment: You should get the value by using C#, then pass it to the query. Note this is a classic case for sql injection.. you should read about that.

Comment: Yep...depending on the characters that are used in the search field (single and double quotes are always a good example).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
public DataTable Test(string connectionString)
    {
        DataTable table = null;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT ID, UnitType, UnitSN, StatusCode, Priority
                                    FROM Units
                                    WHERE UnitSN = @inputTB;";

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@"inputTB", inputTB.Text));

                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    table = new DataTable();
                    adapter.Fill(table);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
           //handle the caught exception 
        }
        return table;
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Please wrap `SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand()` into `using`

Comment: *Never ever* put `catch(Exception ex) {  }` - ignoring *any* exception thrown.